# How to convert lambda expression from a type to another type in Java?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, reflection, properties

I'm using mybatis-plus's `lambda chained query` and it looks like this

```
Long uid = new LambdaQueryChainWrapper(baseMapeer)
            .select(User::getUid)
            .eq(User::getUsername, username)
            .get();
```

I think it's so tedious that I have to write every class, and sometimes I needed to add caching operations, so I write an abstract class to simplify the operation,  like this

```
// abstract service
public <R> T getEntityByUniqueColumn(SFunction<T, R> lambda, R value) {
    // use mybatis-plus util
    final String keyColumn = keyName();
    // USE THIRD-PARTY LIBRARY REFLECTION UTIL
    final String propertyName = reflectProperty(lambda);
    // use mybatis-plus util
    final String columnName = reflectColumn(propertyName);

    return new QueryChainWrapper(baseMapper)
             .select(keyColumn)
             .eq(columnName, value)
             .get();
}

// actual service
public Long getUid(String username) {
    return getEntityByUniqueColumn(User::getUsername, username);
}
```

I'm using the 'de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils' method to get propertyName through get lambda function

```
private String reflectPropertyName(SFunction<T, ?> getXxxSFunc) {
    if (getXxxSFunc == null) return null;
    try {
        return PropertyUtils.getPropertyName(entityClass, getXxxSFunc::apply);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

---

Now the problem arises. PropertyUtils requires a lambda expression with a `TypedPropertyGetter` parameter, while my abstract method provides a lambda expression with an `SFunction` parameter.

The method signature of the former is `V get(T t)`, and the method signature of the latter is `V apply(T t)`. I tried to convert from SFunction to TypedPropertyGetter by using `lambda::apply`.

But I encountered an exception when I executed it. The reason is:
PropertyUtils will eventually check whether the lambda method passed `is call site specific`. If it is, it throws an exception. This means that we cannot express lambda expressions by delegation (there are attributes inside), and we must pass this parameter by user-defined, such as User::getUsername.

```
// source-code
private static void assertHasNoDeclaredFields(Object lambda) {
    if (hasDeclaredFields(lambda)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(lambda + " is call site specific");
    }
}

private static boolean hasDeclaredFields(Object lambda) {
    return lambda.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length > 0;
}
```

There are many methods of abstract classes in my project. I want to know how to convert this lambda expression into another type without delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the source codes of mybatis-plus to findout how it convert the SFunction to db columns. I found the codes in class `AbstractLambdaWrapper`.
It just read the lambda method name and remove 'get', then convert property to column.
Or you could make the abstract service class implements `IService<T>` with Generic Type and make your services extends this abstract class .

```
public abstract class AbstarctService<T> implements IService<T> {

    public <R> T getEntityByUniqueColumn(SFunction<T, R> lambda, R value) {
        return new LambdaQueryChainWrapper<T>(getBaseMapper())
            .select(keyName())
            .eq(lambda, value)
            .getEntity();
    }

    abstract SFunction<T, ?> keyName();
}
```

these may help you in another way.